# Adobe AIR and HNAP (SOAP)

Tags: apache-flex, soap, air

I have been struggling with this for some time now scanning the net for examples or references for executing HNAP calls via an Adobe AIR application using Adobe Flex Builder. I know that making the HNAP calls implements SOAP technology and that AIR can execute SOAP calls. I have even been able to successfully compile and execute example SOAP projects using AIR and Flex.

The examples I have used all reference a WSDL file to define the functions available via the SOAP interface. One big problem is that I have been unable to find a WSDL file defining the HNAP functionality.

Other than trying to create my own WSDL file, which is becoming a real pain, does anyone have any experience or links to references on how to use a SOAP service from AIR and Flex without the use of a WSDL file? Or perhaps information about calling HNAP commands from AIR and Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up creating my own WSDL file in order to make the calls.